# Pass id from URL to next page

Tags: 8, uri

I have made a product page overview that displays all the products of my webshop. On the left, I have placed a filter where people can filter the products (e.g. country can be France, Germany...). When a customer selects a country (e.g. France) the URL changes and the id of the choice (France) is added to the URL. Now I want the next thing: when a customer selects a product, I want that the id that was added in the previous URL also is added to the URL of the product detail page.

So when you have www.test.com/products, you select France, you get `www.test.com/products?field=country%1` and when you select a product, you should get `www.test.com/products/product?field=country%1` instead of just `www.test.com/products/product`...

Anyone who can help?

Comment: You want to have the query string in the page that you are say ?field=country%1 and pass it along with the url(www.test.com/products/product)??

Comment: yes, i want to put the query string after the url

Answer (score 0):

To get the query string use

```
\Drupal::request()->query->all();
```

To further dig into use kint() and debug the  `\Drupal::request()`